# seq -w equivalent in os-x bash

Tags: terminal, osx, seq

I have sub-folders named 00 01 02, ... n with each foldername containing at least 2 digits. I need to access these sub-folders in os-x terminal. The command

```
for i in $(seq -w 00 06); do
echo $i;
done
```

produces an output of `0 1 2 3 4 5 6`. However, the above code in RHEL will produce an output of `00 01 02 03 04 05 06`. How can I enforce mac terminal to produce an output of at least 2 digits similar to RHEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an os-x to try it on, but perhaps this alternative works:

```
seq -f '%02.0f' 0 6
```

Answer (score 0):

OS/X comes with `zsh`, so you can write your script in `zsh` instead (note that you were already using `zsh` syntax (since your `$i` was not quoted which invokes the split+glob operator in `bash`):

```
for x in {00..06}; do
  echo $x
done
```

Posixly, you can always do:

```
x=0; while [ "$x" -le 6 ]; do
  printf '%02d\n' "$x"
  x=$((x + 1))
done
```

Or

```
seq() (first=$1 last=$2 width=${3:-0} step=${4:-1}
  awk "BEGIN{for (i = $first; i <= $last; i += $step)
    printf \"%0${width}d\n\", i}"
)

unset -v IFS # make sure we get the default separator
             # for the split+glob invocation below
for i in $(seq 0 6 2); do
  echo "$i"
done
```